# Cant ssh to ec2 created from AMI of recently patched server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, linux-networking, unix

One of my ec2 instance "patched-server-1" was running of kernel version 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64 and then I did patched the server and current kernel version is 4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64 and I can ssh to the server , then I created an AMI from "patched -server-1" and launched new ec2 instance "patched-server-2" , I cant ssh to it. It give connection refused error.

Reason:
Missing below file under /etc/ssh. These files are missing when I create ec2 instance with the image of upgraded kernel which fails the sshd service start, if I create instance from old kernel only then there is no issue.

```
MISSSING FILES
==============
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         82 May  2 17:30 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----  1 root ssh_keys    387 May  2 17:30 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        162 May  2 17:30 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----  1 root ssh_keys    492 May  2 17:30 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        554 May  2 17:30 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----  1 root ssh_keys   2578 May  2 17:30 ssh_host_rsa_key


ERROR
======

    OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
    debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/sharaddubey/.ssh/known_hosts'
    debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/sharaddubey/.ssh/known_hosts2'
    debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
    debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-6-40-188.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
    ssh: connect to host ec2-3-6-40-188.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```